# Row-by-row fillna with respect to a specific column?

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I have the following pandas dataframe and I would like to fill the NaNs in columns A-C in a row-wise fashion with values from columns D. Is there an explicit way to do this where I can define that all the NaNs should depend row-wise on values in column D? I couldn't find a way to explicitly do this in fillna().

Note that there are additional **columns E-Z** which have their own NaNs and may have other rules for filling in NaNs, and should be **left untouched**.

```
A        B        C        D       E
158      158      158      177     ...  
158      158      158      177     ...
NaN      NaN      NaN      177     ...   
158      158      158      177     ...
NaN      NaN      NaN      177     ...
```

Would like to have this for columns A-C only:

```
A        B        C        D       E
158      158      158      177     ...  
158      158      158      177     ...
177      177      177      177     ...   
158      158      158      177     ...
177      177      177      177     ...
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the `fillna` function:

```
df.fillna(axis=1, method='backfill')
```

will do if there are no NaN's in the other columns.
If there are and you want to leave them untouched, I think the only option in this way is to perform the `fillna` on a subset of your dataframe. With example dataframe:

```
In [45]: df
Out[45]: 
     A    B    C    D   E   F
0  158  158  158  177   1  10
1  158  158  158  177   2  20
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  177   3  30
3  158  158  158  177 NaN  40
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  177   5  50

In [48]: df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']] = df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']].fillna(axis=1, method='backfill')

In [49]: df
Out[49]: 
     A    B    C    D   E   F
0  158  158  158  177   1  10
1  158  158  158  177   2  20
2  177  177  177  177   3  30
3  158  158  158  177 NaN  40
4  177  177  177  177   5  50
```

---

**Udate:** If you don't want to depend on the column order, you can also specify the values to use to fill for each row (like `.fillna(value=df['D']`). The only problem is that this only works for Series (when it is a dataframe, it tries to map the different values to fill to the different columns, not the rows). So with an apply to do it column by column, it works:

```
In [60]: df[['A', 'B', 'C']].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(value=df['D']))
Out[60]: 
     A    B    C
0  158  158  158
1  158  158  158
2  177  177  177
3  158  158  158
4  177  177  177
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. But is there a way to do this by explicitly defining the column that the other NaN-columns should take their value from? E.g. if column 'E' and 'F' were to have NaNs as well and I'd also want them to be filled row-wise with values with from column 'D'? In a sense this would make the fill logic independent of the column orering.

Comment: The `D` column is not always constant as in your example? Because in that case you could do it much simpler of course.

Comment: That's right, it's not constant - I should have chosen a better/less trivial example. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code as well

```
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
df.loc[:,cols] = df.loc[:,cols].bfill()
```